# How to run an Exchange shell command in C sharp?

Tags: c#, exchange-server

How can I run (Exchange 2013) `get-mailboxdatabasecopystatus -databasename` inside of C#?

I've tried many combinations and all of them fail, the most recent being:

```
string un = @"domain\username";
System.Security.SecureString pw = new     System.Security.SecureString();
string password = "password";
foreach (char ch in password)
{
    pw.AppendChar(ch);
}
PSCredential cred = new PSCredential(un, pw);
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();

string cmdlet = "Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus database1";

ps.AddCommand("Set-Variable");

ps.AddParameter("Name", "cred");
ps.AddParameter("Value", cred);

ps.AddScript(@"$session = New-PSSession -configurationname microsoft.exchange -connectionuri http://exchangeserver.com/powershell -auth kerberos -credential $cred");
//ps.AddScript(@"Import-PSSession $session");
ps.AddScript(@"$a = Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {" + cmdlet + "}");
ps.AddScript(@"Remove-PSSession -Session $s");
ps.AddScript(@"echo $a");

foreach (PSObject result in ps.Invoke())
{
    MessageBox.Show(result.Members.ToString());
}
```

Comment: are you getting an error? what's wrong?

Comment: The term $session = New-PSSession -configurationname microsoft.exchange -connectionuri http://exchangeserver.com/powershell -auth kerberos -credential $cred". is not recognized as them name of a cmdlet, function, script file or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or i a path was included verify that the path is correct and try again.

Then it goes into the includes and dlls I'm using.

Comment: Just seeing a working format with get-mailboxdatabasecopystatus, that I could tweak would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some code that worked for me to do a Get-User against Office 365. I don't have a test on-premise Exchange 2013 installation to try that specific cmdlet, but the approach should be very similar, assuming you're doing this from a client machine.

```
PSCredential credentials = new PSCredential(userName, password);

WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(
    new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/PowerShell-LiveID"),
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange",
    credentials);

connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Basic;

using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo))
{
    using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        powershell.AddCommand("Get-User");
        powershell.AddParameter("ResultSize", 50);

        runspace.Open();
        powershell.Runspace = runspace;

        Collection<PSObject> results = powershell.Invoke();

        Console.WriteLine("Results: {0}", results.Count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Jason Johnston very much. With some tweaking of this, I was able to get it to work properly.

Now I need to get a list of Exchange servers in the domain the user is in to auto populate that field.

```
string un = @"domain\username";
            System.Security.SecureString pw = new System.Security.SecureString();
            string password = "password";
            string databaseName = "databasename";
            string exchangeServerName = "http://exchangeserver.com/powershell";
            string microsoftSchemaName = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange";
            foreach (char ch in password)
            {
                pw.AppendChar(ch);
            }
            PSCredential cred = new PSCredential(un, pw);

            WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri(exchangeServerName), microsoftSchemaName, cred);
            connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Kerberos;

            using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo))
            {
                using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create())
                {
                    powershell.AddCommand("Get-Mailboxdatabasecopystatus");
                    powershell.AddParameter("identity", databaseName);
                    powershell.AddCommand("select-object");
                    var props = new string[] { "name", "status" };
                    powershell.AddParameter("property", props);
                    runspace.Open();
                    powershell.Runspace = runspace;

                    Collection<PSObject> results = powershell.Invoke();

                    foreach (PSObject result in results)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
```